# Проблема в установке Dlib и setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, библиотеки, cmake

Я хочу установить на Python 3 библиотеку Dlib. Установил CMake, как я прочитал в Интернете, потом было написано, что надо прописать в консоли:
    `python setup.py install`
Что я и сделал. Но консоль выдала ошибку:
    `python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
Что делать, и как вообще нужно устанавливать библиотеку Dlib, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос текст ошибки как текст

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не перестаю умиляться, как не освоившие установку библиотек люди пытаются заниматься машинным обучением!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, это мне для научки. А насчёт установки библиотек - что в их установке сложного? Это DLib сложна в установке

Comment: Какое именно слово вам непонятно во фразе «'setup.py': No such file»?

Comment: @andreymal, в том то и дело, что файл есть, но он не запускается

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что он есть? `ls`? `dir`?

Comment: @andreymal, через проводник

Comment: @RomatoPotato а нужно проверять, просматривая список файлов в текущем каталоге командной строки, где вы это всё запускаете. Ведь совсем не факт, что в командной строке открыт тот же самый каталог, который вы смотрите в проводнике, и нужно не забыть сделать `cd` куда положено

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. А насчёт установки DLib Вы не могли бы мне помочь? Буду Вам премного благодарен